# iOS: Is there a performance difference between using playInputClick vs the (1104) sound file with audio toolbox?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, audiotoolbox, uiinputviewcontroller

Apple recommends using `playInputClick` in custom keyboards to simulate a click sound. It's easier to implement `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);` so my question then becomes, does `playInputClick` provide better performance or is it the same thing?

Comment: As a side note, if you are still concerned about performance you can run your own benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Reason Apple recommended this is probably not performance.  `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)` will probably always play the same sound but `playInputClick` may play another sound in the future if Apple decides to change the input click sound.

So they are the same right now but it might change and if it does your app will be the only one playing the old sound if you stick to use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)`.