# Official way to use the new keyboard click sounds in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, audio, ios10, iphone-keypad

My app contains a custom control that copies the behaviour of the iOS standard keyboard.

I can successfully play the system keyboard click sound with this code:

```
UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
```

On iOS 9 and below there is only one click sound and this call is all I need. On iOS 10, there are different click sounds for regular keys, for the backspace key and for other special keys.

What is the official way to play these additional sounds? Do I have to use the alternative way from the linked answer? The documentation for `playInputClick()` does not mention anything.

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257353) that suggests to play the new click sounds using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`. But [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27008408) says that these IDs might not point to the latest system click sounds in a future version of iOS. Another problem with the workaround is that there seems to be no way to check if the user has enabled keyboard clicks in the system settings ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055230)).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue...

Answer (score 17):

The url below could help with finding proper sound:
https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

As of **October 2019**, these are the sound IDs

Press Click - ID: 1104

Press Delete - ID: 1155

Press Modifier - ID: 1156

Comment: For me it was 1104 instead of 1123 but I found the 2 others thanks to you!