# Button in UICollectionViewCell Makes Keyboard Sound When Clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` (`CustomCell`), which has a single `UIButton` (`button`) that I want to play a sound when it is pressed. In particular, I want the keyboard letter sounds to play when the variable `isOn` turns to `true` and the keyboard backspace (or delete) sound to play when variable `isOn` turns to `false`.

So far I have the following:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private var isOn = true

    @IBOutlet weak private var button: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    @objc private func toggleButton() {
        if (isOn) {
            /// Play keyboard backspace (delete) sound ...
            UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
        } else {
            /// Play keyboard text sound ...
            UIDevice.current.playInputClick()
        }
        isOn = !isOn
    }

}
```

I also implement the `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` protocol as follows:

```
extension CustomCell: UIInputViewAudioFeedback {
    func enableInputClicksWhenVisible() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

However, no sound is made when the button is pressed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code didn't work because it only works when the view conforming to `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` is the `inputView` of a text field or text view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play keyboard letter sounds :-

```
enum SystemSound: UInt32 {

    case pressClick    = 1123
    case pressDelete   = 1155
    case pressModifier = 1156

    func play() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.rawValue)
    }

}
```

Find proper sound details [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41444536).

So, replace `UIDevice.current.playInputClick()` with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundsID)`

Comment: Thank you very much. This works, however you must also `import AudioToolbox`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness using the accepted answer and the original question:

```
import AudioToolbox
import UIKit

enum SystemSound: UInt32 {

    case click = 1123
    case delete = 1155
    case modifier = 1156

    func play() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.rawValue)
    }

}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private var isOn = true

    @IBOutlet weak private var button: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    @objc private func toggleButton() {
        isOn = !isOn
        let systemSound: SystemSound = (isOn) ? .click : .modifier
        systemSound.play()
    }

}
```